# How can I give my own customer id in customer creation payload for Quickbooks Online V3 API?

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Below is the payload I am using but not able to pass my own customerID on customer creation on quickbooks.

```
{
  "FullyQualifiedName": "King Groceries", 
  "PrimaryEmailAddr": {
    "Address": "jdrew@myemail.com"
  }, 
  "DisplayName": "King's Groceries", 
  "Suffix": "Jr", 
  "Title": "Mr", 
  "MiddleName": "B", 
  "Notes": "Here are other details.", 
  "FamilyName": "King", 
  "PrimaryPhone": {
    "FreeFormNumber": "(555) 555-5555"
  }, 
  "CompanyName": "King Groceries", 
  "BillAddr": {
    "CountrySubDivisionCode": "CA", 
    "City": "Mountain View", 
    "PostalCode": "94042", 
    "Line1": "123 Main Street", 
    "Country": "USA"
  }, 
  "GivenName": "James"
}
```

Tried with "resource_id" and "id" attribute in payload but no luck

Answer (score 1):

> not able to pass my own customerID on customer creation on quickbooks.

QuickBooks does not support what you're trying to do. The `Id` values are generated by QuickBooks (they are an auto-increment integers) and not something that you specify.

If you need to store this value in QuickBooks, use a different field. e.g. there's a `ResaleNum` field which you could put this in. Docs:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/most-commonly-used/customer#the-customer-object